# How to obtain Map Reduce code from Hive Query?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

How does Hive generate a Map Reduce Code automatically for each query and is it possible to view the Map Reduce code generated by Hive for each Query ?

Comment: I am not sure if you can view the generated "code", but you can get a very detailed excecution plan by using: 
`Explain extended query` as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain)

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not generate Map reduce code rather it uses different type of operators like Map Operator, Reduce Operator , Join Operator, Limit Operator...... It uses the corresponding operators based on plan generated from our SQL.

The code for operators can be found in JAR hive-exec.jar
Here is the repository link for the code
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hive/trunk/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/